# how to connect raspberry pi with composite in crt monitor?

Tags: display, setup, noobs, composite-video

I don't have a monitor with hdmi input so I purchased an av cable to connect my raspberry pi 2 model b with a crt tv I have. I have read that the default output of the pi is the hdmi and I tried to change by pressing SHIFT and the 1,2,3etc on my keyboard, as I have read here, but that won't do the trick. I don't know if its the keyboard that doesn't work it lights up though, I was wondering if I could change the default display output from the pc somehow. Needless to say I have downloded, extracted and copied the latest noobs on the sd card can anyone help with all these?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I edited the cmdline.txt adding Display=2 but that didn't help. I conclude that there must be something wrong with the av cable

Answer (score 1):

For help with NOOBS and config.txt see https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs

config.txt settings are shown in http://elinux.org/RPiconfig

Add one of the following settings to /boot/config.txt and reboot.

```
Video mode options

sdtv_mode defines the TV standard for composite output (default=0)

sdtv_mode=0    Normal NTSC
sdtv_mode=1    Japanese version of NTSC – no pedestal
sdtv_mode=2    Normal PAL
sdtv_mode=3    Brazilian version of PAL – 525/60 rather than 625/50, different subcarrier

sdtv_aspect defines the aspect ratio for composite output (default=1)

sdtv_aspect=1  4:3
sdtv_aspect=2  14:9
sdtv_aspect=3  16:9
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but how will I access config.txt?

Comment: @impischi Added a link at start of answer.